# Indexing an array inside an array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have an array inside an array. Normal array indexing fails to work in this case . One way i can solve this problem is that I can convert 'a' into list and then again convert it into an array --a two step process but i want to know is there any other way to slice it so that the structure of 'a' remains unchanged ?

```
a=np.array([[np.arange(3)],[np.arange(6,9)],[np.arange(11,14)]])
array([[[ 0,  1,  2]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[11, 12, 13]]])

a.shape
(3L, 1L, 3L)

a.ndim
3

type(a)
numpy.ndarray
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: What makes you think that normal indexing fails, and what exactly do you mean when saying that?

Comment: if i use 
a=np.array([np.arange(3),np.arange(6,9),np.arange(11,14)]) instead of my above code then this becomes case of 2d array whose indexing i refer to normal in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have an unnecessary level of nesting there, in case you can
initialize your array like this

```
a=np.array([np.arange(3),np.arange(6,9),np.arange(11,14)])
```

then you can access its elements with standard notation

```
a[1,1]
```

If the level of nesting is not incorrect, then you can still access **a**'s elements like this:

```
a[1,0,1]
```

Basically, the problem is that you are wrapping the second-level array inside another array of dimension 1, so when you access its elements you need to keep in mind that.

Comment: Yes i know the other way around of writing but i am just wondering how can one deal with if this happened .

Comment: If you look at the result of 'a.shape', you are given the exact dimensions associated with your n-dimensional array. If you don't know in advance the dimension of your array, just query it and use dynamic evaluation (or some other trick). It's quite slower, though.

Comment: Can you mention how you indexed 'a' in the above answer more clearly . I mean where do these numbers pointing at and in what order ? like a[rowno,columnno] etc we do in 2d array .Thanks . and if you have any material which you thing is helpful to me for better understanding 3d array please provide me the link.

Comment: **a**'s shape is (3, 1, 3), that means that to index any of its elements you need 3 indexes. The first must be in [0,2] because the first dimension is 3, the second must be within [0,0] because the second dimension is 1 and the third must be within [0,2] again because the third dimension is 3. If you don't know in advance what the structure of the array is, you can make a recursive function for iterating over each dimension of the array till you get to the final element. Or you can compose the indexes with a loop cycle as a string and then use eval() to access the location. Is it clear?

Comment: Yes somewhat it is clear. I have one more question . what these (3,1,3) represent in 3d array as in 2d array (x,y) represent (row no,colno) . Please explain

Comment: The names, `row`, `col`, `depth` or what ever don't really matter. The way 3d arrays are displayed it may be easier to think in terms of `plane`, `row`, `col`.  Or just stick with the axis number, `0,1,2...`.

Answer (score 1):

Compare your 2 arrays:

```
In [39]: a=np.array([[np.arange(3)],[np.arange(6,9)],[np.arange(11,14)]])
In [40]: a1=np.array([np.arange(3),np.arange(6,9),np.arange(11,14)])
In [41]: a
Out[41]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[11, 12, 13]]])
In [42]: a.shape       
Out[42]: (3, 1, 3)      # 3d
In [43]: a1
Out[43]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [11, 12, 13]])
In [44]: a1.shape
Out[44]: (3, 3)     # 2d
```

One way to remove the size 1 dimension is with `squeeze`:

```
In [45]: np.squeeze(a)
Out[45]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [11, 12, 13]])
```

or reshape:

```
In [46]: a.reshape(3,3)
Out[46]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [11, 12, 13]])
```

You treat the 3 dimensions of `a` in exactly the same was the 2 of `a1`:

```
In [47]: a1[1,:]
Out[47]: array([6, 7, 8])      # index 1 dim of the 2
In [48]: a[1,:]
Out[48]: array([[6, 7, 8]])    # index 1 dim of the 3
In [49]: a[1,0,:]
Out[49]: array([6, 7, 8])      # index 2 dim of the 3
```

Comment: thanks for putting efforts to answer the question. But i don't want to change the structure of my 3d array .any other way you know to deal with 3d array without changing its dimensions?

Comment: Deal in what way?  I showed how to index it. Normal array indexing works the same with 3d as with 2.

Comment: like patrick mentioned his way without changing the dimension in the above comments. I am looking for better explaination of the patrick comment . Converting it into 2d array do the stuff i know but i am not sure what will happen to existing 3d array when i convert it to 2d array and other properties or calculations as i dont have real time experience with 3d array . so i just want to preserve the dimension of 3d array and not preferring to change its dimension. I am a newbie in numpy so just learning things. guide me as i stuck. thanks

Comment: Just play about with these arrays in an interactive session.  You don't have to have 'real time experience' with 3d or 4d arrays; the experience is in the computer, not the physical world.